# Internal exception occurs in org.springframework.integration.dsl.filter(...) method

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-rabbit, spring-integration-dsl

We observed DLQ messages are missing trace stack in RabbitMq when the runtime exception is originated in the execution scope of org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.filter(...) method.

For example, using the following code snippet:

```
@Bean
IntegrationFlow accountingMovementFlow(final Function<AccountingMovement, AccountingMovement> tranMoveMapValEnricher, final MessageChannel auditDiscardChannel, final Clock clock
) {
    return from("dltmvChannel")
            .transform(Message.class, message -> (Message<?>) MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
                    .setHeader(SINK_STARTED_TIMESTAMP, LocalDateTime.ofInstant(clock.instant(), ZoneId.of("UTC")).toString())
                    .build())

            .transform(new AccountingMovementMapper())
            .filter(AccountingMovement::isValidOperationType,
                    discardFlow -> discardFlow.discardChannel(auditDiscardChannel))
            .filter(AccountingMovement.class, accountingMovement -> accountingMovement.getAccountBusinessDate().isBefore(accountingMovement.getMovementEffectiveDate()),
                    discardFlow -> discardFlow.discardChannel(auditDiscardChannel))

            .transform(tranMoveMapValEnricher::apply)
            .filter(AccountingMovement.class, accountingMovement -> !accountingMovement.isExistingMovement(),
                    discardFlow -> discardFlow.discardChannel(auditDiscardChannel))

            .channel("accountingMovementEnricherChannel")
            .get();
}
```

Let's say AccountBusinessDate is null.  Executing accountingMovement.getAccountBusinessDate().isBefore(accountingMovement.getMovementEffectiveDate()) will immediately trigger a NullPointerException.  In this case, the message which flows into "dltmvChannel" will get stored in the DLQ with trace stack.  However, this is not happening.

We traced/debugged the .filter(...) method and found the internal execution actually triggers another parse exception as the original runtime exception is bubbling up.  As a result, the DLQ'ed message is missing the trace stack.

We don't see this behavior in the other methods of org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.  For example, if tranMoveMapValEnricher::apply triggers a runtime exception in while executing org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.transform(...), the message gets DLQ'ed with trace stack.

Comment: You need to show the rest of your configuration upstream of this flow.

Comment: That NPE on the `isBefore()` is bubbled any way. There  should be some error handling upstream in your parent flow. It might be the fact that you do some additional logic there on the `errorChannel`